# VirtualHosts fallback to rewriting URL

Tags: apache, dns, url-rewriting, virtualhost, subdomain

I'm setting up an Apache web server, and I have a bunch of VirtualHost entries in my httpd.conf, which all work fine. All subdomain requests on my domain (eg. test.mydomain.com, test2.mydomain.com) are sent to the same IP address (same server). I'd like to rewrite any unrecognized subdomains to simply www.mydomain.com or just mydomain.com if there isn't a VirtualHost entry for them. Is this achievable using Apache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a Redirect rule in your default VirtualHost (ie, the one that's used when accessing the server via a host without a VirtualHost):

```
Redirect permanent / http://example.com/
```

If that doesn't suit your needs (like if you want to still be able to access some files on the fallback DocumentRoot), you could set a PHP script as your 404 handler:

#### httpd.conf

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

#### 404.php

```
<?php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://example.com");
```